# Vanishing of photon one-point function in QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

I would like to know why the photon one-point function vanishes in QED. I am aware that any $n$-point functions vanishes for odd $n$ because of 'charge-conjugate" argument, this does not apply to $n=1$ case. Here I want to know how to see the quantity
$$
\int \frac{d^4x}{(2\pi)^4}tr\left[ \gamma^a(\frac{1}{-k+m})\right]
$$
vanishes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are asking for is $\langle A_\mu(x) \rangle$. Now what could it be? It can't depend on $x$ by translation invariance, so it would have to be a constant four-vector, but as long as the theory is Lorentz invariant there are no constant four-vectors except for $0$.

More concretely, the integral diverges (cubically!) so it must be regularised. Any regularisation which respects Lorentz invariance must give a zero result by the above argument. You might want to try out dimensional regularisation or Pauli-Villars to see this.

---

EDIT: Expanding a bit. First, you can simplify the propagator by multiplying top and bottom by $\not{k} + m$. The term proportional to $m$ vanishes because of the trace. The trace is then proportional to $k_a$. The integral is (up to a constant factor)

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{4}k}{\left(2\pi\right)^{4}}\frac{k_{a}}{k^{2}-m^{2}+i\epsilon}$$

This needs to be regularised. Consider Pauli-Villars regularisation. It is easy to show that (since the divergence is cubic) you need two regulator scales to define the integral. We take $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2\gg m,k$ (and eventually the limit $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2\rightarrow\infty$), and regulate the integral as

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{4}k}{\left(2\pi\right)^{4}} k_a\frac{\left(m^2-\Lambda_1^2\right) \left(m^2-\Lambda_2^2\right)}{\left(k^2-\Lambda_1^2+i \epsilon \right) \left(k^2-\Lambda_2^2+i \epsilon \right) \left(k^2-m^2+i \epsilon \right)}$$

Note that the limit $\Lambda_1,\Lambda_2\rightarrow\infty$ formally gives you back the expression you want and that the whole thing is Lorentz invariant and convergent.

Now it is trivial to show rigourously that the integral vanishes: due to the $k_a$ in the integrand, which is an odd function of $k_a$, while the rest of the integral is even.

This type of argument is often applied *without* regulating the integral, but the resulting argument would be heuristic, whereas with the regulator it is rigourously correct. You eventually get the hang of when these short-cuts work and when they don't.

Comment: So it does diverge but we must set it to be zero because of the Lorenz invariance.

Comment: It must be regulated for the integral to be *defined*. Then, once that is done, assuming the regulator is Lorentz invariant, the integral *evaluates* to zero. It's not as simple as just setting it to zero.

Comment: I thought the integration of an odd function over a symmetric range is always zero. I mean, the argument would be valid even for a divergent integral.

Comment: (Another argument is...  )

"...so it would have to be a constant four-vector" And the only four-vector available in the problem is the photon's momentum, which must be zero by conservation of momentum for $\langle A^\mu\rangle$.