# Proof of Furry's theorem

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, charge-conjugation

i was wondering if anyone could give an explicit calculation or show a link that shows the proof to [Furry's theorem](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=furry+theorem+qed+proof). showing how the vacuum expectation value of any odd number of electromagnetic currents vanishes. in particular the case for $n=3$.

Comment: Wait, are you after the n=3 or the n=1 case?

Comment: i was after the photon one loop n=3 case.

Comment: Did you just try to copy the question from here, almost word for word?? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54812/

Comment: @alejandro123 : See a short proof [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~fionnf/qft/furry.pdf) in .pdf format. It is the first result in google.

Comment: I was looking for an actual proof carrying out the calculation of the integral from Feynman's diagram.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the fact that the electromagnetic current changes sign under charge conjugation i.e $Cj^{\mu\nu}C^{\dagger} = -j^{\mu\nu}$ and thus the vaccum expectation of all diagrams withodd number of em legs vanishes